# Creating a new div (with its content) for each row in the database

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a feature, where users can post `thoughts` and users can add **comments** to each `thought` The way it works is that, when the `comments` link is clicked, all comments associated with that `thought_id` will be loaded.

Here is the structure of my `user_comments` table:

```
   id
   body_of_msg
   comment_posted_by
   comment_posted_to
   post_id (which is the id of a thought from the `user_thoughts` table)
```

Consider the following data:

`user_thoughts` table (1 row):

```
 id: 184
 thought: "hello, this is a thought from anderson."
```

Assume I have two rows in the `user_comments` table:

```
   id: 1
   body_of_msg: Comment assigned to thought_id of 184
   comment_posted_by: conor
   comment_posted_to: anderson
   post_id: 184

   id: 2
   body_of_msg: Another comment assigned to thought_id of 184
   comment_posted_by: alice
   comment_posted_to: anderson
   post_id: 184
```

**Problem**: At the moment, when I click the `comments` link, only one of the comments is being shown (the latest comment is being shown, so in this case, Alice's comment).

**Here is the code**:

```
<?php
    // Get the comments attached to a users post...
    $get_comm = mysqli_query ($connect, "SELECT * FROM user_comments WHERE post_id='$thought_id' ORDER BY post_id DESC");
    $num_of_comments = mysqli_num_rows($get_comm); // get number of comments for each post by post_id
    // if there are comments for the post, get its content
    if ($num_of_comments !=0 || $num_of_comments == 0){ 
    while(  $comment = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($get_comm)){
            $comment_body           = $comment['body_of_msg'];
            $comment_posted_to      = $comment['comment_posted_to'];
            $comment_posted_by      = $comment['comment_posted_by'];
            $removed                = $comment['comment_removed'];
    }
    echo   "";          
            /** There are other divs and content echo'd here**/
           ////////////////////////////////////////////
            // this is where each comment is displayed
            echo "
            <div id='toggleComment$thought_id' class='new_comment' style='display:none;'>
                <br/><b><a href = 'profile_page/$comment_posted_by'> $comment_posted_by said</a></b>: $comment_body "; ?><?php
                    if ($comment_posted_by == $username){
                            echo "<a id='remove_comment' href = '/inc/remove_comment.php'> Delete </a>";                        
                        } echo "
            </div>";
            /////////////////////////////////////////////   
    }
?>
```

Where `$thought_id` comes from:

```
$count = mysqli_query ($connect, "SELECT * FROM user_thoughts");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_thoughts_from_db)) {
    $thought_id      = $row['id'];
}
```

**What I think**:
This could just be me struggling to find a solution, but, could it be that each comment is overlapping the other? My comment feature involved comments dynamically appearing below the thought, so I have utilized Javascript, to achieve this. Just thinking the block may be getting replaced by a new comment?

**What I have tried**:

```
while(  $comment = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($get_comm)){
        $comment_body           = $comment['body_of_msg'];
        $comment_posted_to      = $comment['comment_posted_to'];
        $comment_posted_by      = $comment['comment_posted_by'];
        $removed                = $comment['comment_removed'];
        // this is where each comment is displayed
        echo "
        <div id='toggleComment$thought_id' class='new_comment' style='display:none;'>
            <br/><b><a href = 'profile_page/$comment_posted_by'> $comment_posted_by said</a></b>: $comment_body "; ?><?php
                if ($comment_posted_by == $username){
                        echo "<a id='remove_comment' href = '/inc/remove_comment.php'> Delete </a>";                        
                    } echo "
        </div>";
        } 
    }
```

This still only shows one comment, when there are two to be shown.

[image]

Comment: You need to echo the comments in your while loop.  Right now, you're setting the variables during each iteration, but only the last one gets echoed in your div after you've exited the loop.

Comment: @AdamKonieska - I have tried, that, but it still only shows one row. I have edited my question to show exactly where I have echo's the div.

Comment: You're setting `display: none;` on them.  Are you sure they aren't being echoed?  What is the value of `$num_of_comments`?

Comment: @AdamKonieska - `$num_of_comments` returns the value of `2`, which is  true, since their are 2 rows in the table. But only one row is being shown. I will edit my answer to provide an image, maybe it will better illustrate the issue.

Comment: Freddy, the image isn't helpful because it doesn't show the full markup being rendered.  Check the source, and post the rendered HTML output here.  Based on what you have so far, it looks like both comments should be echoed, but `display: none;` may be hiding them from the user.

Comment: Can you join this chat room - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106931/creating-a-new-div-with-its-content-for-each-row-in-the-database - so we can discuss this further?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use ajax? I had done a site web that use comments (like stackoverflow) and I used a lot ajax for that. Of course, all the creations of html elements will be done in js and what you will return from php will be only json (containing the content of comments and its info). 
This will help you also to load new comments without refreshing the page (setInterval).

**For the answer**, I have find **three** things that are strange, the first one is

```
if ($num_of_comments !=0 || $num_of_comments == 0){
```

which will be always true. The second thing  is the fact that the echo is outside the while bloc (this probably the cause of having one comment echoed). The last thing is display none that you put in the style of the html element. So what I suggest you is to make the echo in the while block or to make an array of comments and make  an iterator. After that, try to use the inspector tool of your browser to see if the code source returned contain only one comment or more. This will help you to see if the php works or not.